# What's the expected overhead of a passthrough device mapper?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, performance, device-mapper, ramdisk

I'm trying to establish a baseline throughput overhead for a passthrough device mapper; i.e. a device mapper that does nothing. Roughly following benchmarking procedures [from Cloudflare](https://blog.cloudflare.com/speeding-up-linux-disk-encryption), I'm measuring roughly **30% throughput decrease** from using a passthrough device mapper over ramdisk with fio, as opposed to straight I/Os to ramdisk, running on Azure VMs, GCP VMs, and raw metal machines, with both Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and 22.04 LTS.

**Is this expected?**

I'm getting roughly 1000+MB/s over ramdisk across devices and 600+MB/s for passthrough.

Here's my setup for those of you who would like to replicate my results:

1. Create a Ubuntu 20.04 or 22.04 VM or get access to such a machine. Turn off secure boot so you can load kernel modules.
2. Create 4GB of ramdisk: `sudo modprobe brd rd_nr=1 rd_size=4194304`
3. Install fio: `sudo apt install -y fio`
4. Run fio over ramdisk: `sudo fio --filename=/dev/ram0 --readwrite=readwrite --bs=4k --direct=1 --loops=20 --name=plain`
5. Record the read/write throughput at the bottom of the output: `aggrb=?MB/s`. This is the baseline.

Now for the passthrough device mapper, using the "delay" device mapper. This is what was done by [Cloudflare](https://www.usenix.org/sites/default/files/conference/protected-files/vault20_slides_korchagin.pdf):

1. Set up the passthrough device mapper: `echo '0 8388608 delay /dev/ram0 0 0' | sudo dmsetup create plain`
2. Run fio over it: `sudo fio --filename=/dev/mapper/plain --readwrite=readwrite --bs=4k --direct=1 --loops=20 --name=plain`
3. Record the throughput similarly.

Alternatively, if you suspect the "delay" device mapper with 0 delay is not performant, you can use my implementation of a passthrough device [here](https://github.com/davidchuyaya/rollbaccine/blob/main/src/passthrough/passthrough.c).
Download both files [here](https://github.com/davidchuyaya/rollbaccine/tree/main/src/passthrough), then compile and load the kernel module:

1. Run `make`
2. Load the module: `sudo insmod passthrough.ko`
3. Load the device mapper: `` echo "0 `sudo blockdev --getsz /dev/ram0` passthrough /dev/ram0" | sudo dmsetup create passthrough ``
4. Run fio over it: `sudo fio --filename=/dev/mapper/passthrough --readwrite=readwrite --bs=4k --direct=1 --loops=20 --name=passthrough`
5. Record the throughput similarly.

Comment: You are right, my answer was for the disks, but I though it maybe also used for ram disks.  I have deleted the answer as I'm not sure.